# <p-editor> can not bind [ngModel]

Tags: typescript, npm, primeng, text-editor, ngmodel

`Here i am using **primeng : ^14.2.2** ,**angular: ^14.2.2**,**quill: ^2.0.0-dev.4**,**quill-better-table: ^1.2.10**.Data comes from data base but the ngModel not binded in the text editor.

**request.html**:
**`<p-editor name="longdesc" [(ngModel)]="requestType.longDescription"                                      [style]="{'height':'220px'}"></p-editor>**`
**app.module.ts**:

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import QuillBetterTable from 'quill-better-table';
Quill.register({
    'modules/better-table': QuillBetterTable,
    'modules/blotFormatter': BlotFormatter,
}, true);

// @ts-expect-error. We a
```

re forcing the below type change for making primeng's editor work with new versions of quill (v2)
Quill.prototype.pasteHTML = function (html: string) { return this.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(html); }

```
ngmodel need to bind in the text editor`
```